# Cursor.getType throw error for empty result

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-cursor

When I tried below code I found `res.getType(i)` throw an error for empty (but the existing table):

```
private HashMap<String,ColumnTypeEnum> getTableColumns(String tableName){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE 1=2";
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        res.moveToFirst();//I removed this part but I got no result too
        int columnCount = res.getColumnCount();
        String[] columNames = res.getColumnNames();
        HashMap<String, ColumnTypeEnum> columns = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            columns.put(columNames[i], ColumnTypeEnum.getEnum(res.getType(i)));
        }
        res.close();
}
```

And console output is:

```
W/System.err: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getType(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:130)
W/System.err:     at backend.Database.DB.getTableColumns(DB.java:198)
W/System.err:     at backend.Database.DB.insert(DB.java:151)
W/System.err:     at backend.BaseActivity.BaseActivity.insert(BaseActivity.java:264)
W/System.err:     at backend.WebView.Controller.SimpleController.InsertToDB(SimpleController.java:47)
                  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I already read [android cursor guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) but there is no answer for my question. My purpose for this code is getting columns information based on the given table name.

Comment: In your SQL statement I see `WHERE 1=2`. `1` is the name of a column?

Comment: This is for getting no data from DB and nothing more and is totally normal

Comment: Ok thanks for explanation

Comment: What I think is bug because they have no row the error said `size of 0` with `index of 0`.

Comment: You need to check if `moveToFirst()` return true to execute your statement otherwise they bug. Add a if statement.

Comment: And our purpose is getting JUST information about columns so we don't need data. for this reason best where clause is `1=2` that is always false (for any table with any columns)

Comment: `moveToFirst` will always return false dear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176673/discussion-between-crammeur-and-yashar-aliabasi).

Answer (score 2):

sqlite has [dynamic typing](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and column type depends on the data value. Trying to deduce column type without data won't work.

You could remove the column type to go with just column names, or query [`sqlite_master`](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) to get the SQL that was used when creating the table.

Comment: thank you for the response. Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful answer from @laalto.
following that, you can only get the create table query from `sqlite_master` table
using

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master where type = 'table' and tbl_name = 'table_name'
```

where *table_name* is your table name.

the other obvious solution coming to my mind is to use **limit 1** with your current query.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " limit 1";
```

this query's cursor point to some data then you can find the column datatype,except the null values obviously.

Comment: Your second solution will not work for Empty tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to read row 0 (the first row) when there are no rows to be read.

This is because you are not checking if there are rows to be read. You can check either by using the Cursor's `getCount()` method or by checking the result of a Cursor's `move????` method.

i.e. Most of the `move????` methods will return false if the move could not be made. e.g. you could use `if (res.moveToFirst()) { ..... do your stuff } else { .... handle no rows if needed }`.

#### However, considering your comment :-

> And our purpose is getting JUST information about columns so we don't
>   need data. for this reason best where clause is 1=2 that is always
>   false (for any table with any columns)

Then, you can ascertain the column types by using the `table_info` PRAGMA statment, which does not require extraction of the column type from the SQL that can be obtained from sqlite_master.

You could have a universal/common method such as :-

```
public Cursor getTableInfo(String table) {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + table + ")",null);
}
```

And then invoke this, as an example, using something like :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String col_table_info_cid = "cid";
    public static final String col_table_info_name = "name";
    public static final String col_table_info_type = "type";
    public static final String col_table_info_notnull = "notnull";
    public static final String col_table_info_default_value = "dflt_value";
    public static final String col_table_info_primary_key = "pk";

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        String table_to_look_at = "gameinfo"; //<<<<< The table to look at
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getTableInfo(table_to_look_at);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Columns for Table " + table_to_look_at);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            sb.append("\n\tColumn Name=")
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(col_table_info_name)))
                    .append(" Column Type=")
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(col_table_info_type)))
            ;
        }
        Log.d("TABLE INFO",sb.toString());
}
```

The above could result in :-

> ```
> 07-24 22:27:19.842 1255-1255/ga.gamesapp D/TABLE INFO: Columns for Table gameinfo
>       Column Name=_id Column Type=INTEGER
>       Column Name=name Column Type=TEXT
>       Column Name=category Column Type=TEXT
>       Column Name=games Column Type=TEXT
>       Column Name=weird Column Type=rumplestiltskin
> ```

#### However is this of any use?

As can be seen from the above result column **weird** has a column type of **rumplestiltskin**. This means little unless you look at [3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), which would result in a column affinity of **NUMERIC** (*rule **5** is applied as no other rules apply*).

You could have a routine to determine the column's type affinity, such as :-

```
private String determineColumnAffinity(String columntype) {
    String uc = columntype.toUpperCase();
    //rule 1
    if (uc.indexOf("INT") > -1) {
        return "INTEGER";
    }
    //rule 2
    if ((uc.indexOf("CHAR") > -1) || (uc.indexOf("CLOB") > -1) || (uc.indexOf("TEXT") > -1)) {
        return "TEXT";
    }
    //rule 3
    if ((uc.length() < 1) || (uc.indexOf("BLOB") > -1)) {
        return "BLOB";
    }
    if ((uc.indexOf("REAL") > -1) || (uc.indexOf("FLOA") > -1) || (uc.indexOf("DOUB") > -1)) {
        return "REAL";
    }
    return "NUMERIC";
}
```

If amending the above code to be :-

```
        sb.append("\n\tColumn Name=")
                .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(col_table_info_name)))
                .append(" Column Type=")
                .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(col_table_info_type)))
                .append(" Column Affinity=")
                .append(determineColumnAffinity(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(col_table_info_type))))
        ;
```

The you would get :-

> ```
> 07-24 22:59:57.770 1408-1408/ga.gamesapp D/TABLE INFO: Columns for Table gameinfo
>       Column Name=_id Column Type=INTEGER Column Affinity=INTEGER
>       Column Name=name Column Type=TEXT Column Affinity=TEXT
>       Column Name=category Column Type=TEXT Column Affinity=TEXT
>       Column Name=games Column Type=TEXT Column Affinity=TEXT
>       Column Name=weird Column Type=rumplestiltskin Column Affinity=NUMERIC
> ```

**However**, even still, this may be of little use as again when referring to [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), these little gems can be found :-

- > SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
  >   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
  >   container.
- > However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are
  >   not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.
- > Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
  >   KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

As such, in the gameinfo table used above, with the exception of the **_id** column, which is an alias of the rowid column (and can therefore only store an INTEGER), any type of value can be stored in any type of column, so the definition if the column type's significance can largely be irrelevant.

For instance the following is an example of a valid, albeit perhaps useless, table that shows different data types stored in columns (data type is colour coded) :-

[image]

- Note although the type definition has been stated as being largely irrelevant, it can be relevant to type used to store the data (Storage Type) and thus the result returned via the typeof function [Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof). So **a good understanding of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) may be needed**.

#### Additional re comment :-

> I mean querying directly from Sqlite is the only way to get columns
>   info?

You can obtain column names from an empty cursor, but you cannot get the column type as this requires access to a column within a row.

e.g. The following will work :-

```
    Cursor csr2 = mDBHlpr.getAllRows(); // get rows from empty table
    csr2.moveToFirst();
    sb = new StringBuilder("Columns for Table");
    for(int i=0; i < (csr2.getColumnCount());i++) {
        int ctype = 100; //<<<<<<<<<< NOT A VALID COLUMN TYPE
        //ctype = csr2.getType(i); //<<<<<<<<<< cannot get the type unless there is a row
        String type = "unknown";
        switch (ctype) {
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                type= "REAL";
                break;
             case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                 type = "NULL";
                 break;
             case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                 type = "INTEGER";
                 break;
             case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                 type = "TEXT";
                 break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                type = "BLOB";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\n\tColumn Name=").append(csr2.getColumnName(i))
                .append(" Column Type=")
                .append(type)
                .append(" Column Affinity=")
                .append(determineColumnAffinity(type));
    }
    Log.d("TABLE INFO 2",sb.toString());
    csr2.close();
```

But removing the commented out line will result in an `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` exception, if the table (therefore the Cursor) is empty.

- 0 as theorectically the cursor has been moved to the first row.
- without the csr2.moveToFirst() then Index would be -1

  - (i.e. Cursor is at before the first row)

**Therefore, unless there is data in the table, you cannot ascertain the column types without resorting to utilising SQLite directly**

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.Will `getTableInfo` work in any android version? I mean querying directly from `Sqlite` is the only way to get columns info?

Comment: It certainly works as far back as API 16 (the above was tested on 16). It should cover all version of SQLite3 as it was introduced back in 2001-10-09 (SQLIte 2.0.2). There is no guarantee that it will remain as per *Specific pragma statements may be removed and others added in future releases of SQLite. There is no guarantee of backwards compatibility.* [PRAGMA Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info). However, it's probably very unlikely to be removed (due to maintaining backward compatibility).

Comment: *I mean querying directly from Sqlite is the only way to get columns info?* Drat, was going to check that out and forgot. Will look into it.